# AWS Rekognition vs AWS visual search

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-rekognition

Currently, I need to implement searching products by image on my app. As doing research, I wanna go for aws rekognition. So when the model predicts the image, I can pass the predicted label to query products by my api. This is what I plan to do. However, I also come across aws visual search (using aws sageMaker) which is way beyond my understanding. So, am I on the right way to implement it by using the first option (aws rekognition ) ???

Answer (score 1):

**Amazon Rekognition** is 'out-of-the-box' image recognition. It can label pictures, find faces, read text, etc. It accepts [custom labels](https://aws.amazon.com/rekognition/custom-labels-features/), however it is not possible to modify the general recognition process.

**Amazon SageMaker** is a machine learning platform for building your own models. It is highly flexible, for everything from image recognition through to predictive analytics. However, it is quite complex and is usually used by Data Scientists.

Given your knowledge levels, Amazon Rekognition would be a better choice for you.

Comment: yes, I am training the model with custom labels, after getting label, I will pass it to query my products. So, is it a good solution? and is it possible to have multiple labels from one image?

Comment: I can merely recommend that you try Amazon Rekognition and see whether it is capable of meeting the goals of your task. Images can return multiple labels with different confidence levels (eg Swimming Pool and Party).

Comment: thank you so much sir, and we use aws amplify to make the prediction from mobile app or web app, right? And,  I am testing the custom labels, i have only two classes. How can I get multiple labels with different confidence levels?